# How to use an outside built variable in my function in R

Tags: r, function, global, local

I've been struggling for a while with this :
I try to use a variable which is built in the global environnement inside my function code.

Here is my code :

```
adressbrouillon="C/Data/..."
load_all <- function() {
load(paste(adressbrouillon,"work.RData",sep=""))
}
```

When I run :

```
load_all()
```

Nothing happens.

However, when I run this command :

```
load(paste(adressbrouillon,"work.RData",sep=""))
```

That's works very well!

Can anyone tell me what's happen and what to do to get my load_all function work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
load_all <- function() {
    load(paste(adressbrouillon,"work.RData",sep=""), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

If you don't specify `envir`, the data is loaded into a temporary environment which is destroyed when the function returns.